Does anyone have Venmo payments working
Anyone got Venmo ( part of Omnipay extension ) working?
Paypal checkout configured according to this guide https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/blob/master/docs/Paypal.md
and Venmo prerequisites met - a person having Venmo installed on their app and located in the US.
However there is no Venmo button on contribution pages. Could it be because of Venmo API retirement ( https://venmo.com/docs/overview/ || https://venmo.com/developers/ )? Any pointers re: how to make it work please?

I'm trying to do the same thing.  I don't think it's the API retirement (but can't be certain) because the current PayPal docs show the Venmo button.  But maybe it's because it's the REST v1 endpoint?  I'm going to submit a ticket to PayPal tech support tomorrow most likely.

@JonG-MegaphoneTech Thank you Jon, their documentation is a bit confusing  - there are a lot of places here and there mentioning Venmo and it doesn't look like there is a single trustworthy source. Please keep us updated, cheers!

@yurg I worked on this a bit more today, and I have something working.
There are a number of criteria that must be met for the Venmo button to appear.  We must a) not be using recurring payments, b) not trying to save the card to a PayPal "vault", c) we must specifically request Venmo.

When we have a createBillingAgreement() function, PayPal assumes this is recurring, and disables Venmo. So I changed that to createOrder().
I removed vault=true from the URL so it knows we're not trying to save the card.
I added enable-funding=venmo.

My diff is below. Please test and let me know if it's working for you!
diff --git a/Metadata/js/omnipay_PaypalRest.js b/Metadata/js/omnipay_PaypalRest.js
index bf784ac13..6aa608ca5 100644
--- a/Metadata/js/omnipay_PaypalRest.js
+++ b/Metadata/js/omnipay_PaypalRest.js
@@ -31,7 +31,7 @@
           });
         },
 
-        createBillingAgreement: function (data, actions) {
+        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
 
           var frequencyInterval = $('#frequency_interval').val() || 1;
           var frequencyUnit = $('#frequency_unit').val() ? $('#frequency_interval').val() : CRM.vars.omnipay.frequency_unit;
@@ -93,7 +93,7 @@
       .render('#paypal-button-container');
   }
 
-  var paypalScriptURL = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=' + CRM.vars.omnipay.client_id + '&currency=' + CRM.vars.omnipay.currency + '&commit=false&vault=true';
+  var paypalScriptURL = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=' + CRM.vars.omnipay.client_id + '&currency=' + CRM.vars.omnipay.currency + '&commit=false&enable-funding=venmo'
   CRM.loadScript(paypalScriptURL, false).done(renderPaypal);


Thank you, it works both via VPN or "buyer-country=US" for those not in the US, according to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/pay-with-venmo/integrate/
